# Do i need keystore selection in android application export

Tags: android

why do it need keystore selection for exporting android project to other location.

it gives two options, existing and create new.

can we achieve bypassing it.

are there any other uses of this keystore.

Comment: Do you mean Export Application Package?

Comment: keystore is required to sign the APK before you publish it to the market/playstore. By default, eclipse uses the debug.keystore which is auto generated by ADT, and all apks generated by eclipse are signed using this keystore. If you are trying to simply export the project use a file system option like archive

Comment: @Elenasys, i want to move project folder location from one place to another

Comment: ok in that case you will have no problems, when you sing your app just browse the Keystore, but i think im misunderstanding your question, you want to move all the project folder to another location? do you mean another Workspace?

Comment: @Elenasys, i have my git pointed to some folder, but ecliplse has its own workspace where project is half the way, i donot want to change my  git location, instead i want to move that project folder / workspace to git location

Answer (score 0):

You will create a new Keystore, but if you have an application in Google Playstore created with a Keystore you have to use the same Keystore, you can copy your current Keystore and use it in "other location".

Read more about this:

[**Android App Signing**](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#cert)

> **Warning**: Keep the keystore file you generate with Keytool in a safe,
>   secure place. You must use the same key to sign future versions of
>   your application. If you republish your app with a new key, Google
>   Play will consider it a new app. For more information on settings that
>   must remain constant over the life of your app, see the Android
>   Developer Blog